# LibVlcsharp Winforms Adjusting video options not working (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, libvlcsharp

could someone help me solve my problem.
i am switching from a VLC.Dotnet player to VLCsharp.
so fare everything is ok i converted everything from VLC.Dotnet with no problems except the video option like: brightness, contrast...
i am using:

```
_mp.SetAdjustFloat(LibVLCSharp.Shared.VideoAdjustOption.Brightness, 1.35)
```

but nothing happens.
And also:

```
_mp.SetAdjustInt(LibVLCSharp.Shared.VideoAdjustOption.Brightness, 2)
```

i am using:

```
Public _mp As MediaPlayer
```

i don't know what i'am doing wrong
please help.
a solution in C# is welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, the options are working if I do this:

```
_mp.SetAdjustFloat(LibVLCSharp.Shared.VideoAdjustOption.Enable, True)
```